# WooCommerce custom place order validation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, add-filter

I would like to do som additional checks when the user has submitted an order in Woocommerce. Have tried using different add_filter methods, but it seems that I can't hook up to a place_order filter. I have tried with:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_place_order', 'checkFields'); //on ordersubmit
function checkFields(){
  if($this != true){
    //not allowed to place order because of data is not true
  }else{
   //continue order
  }
}
```

But non of above is being triggered when I submit the checkout form.
Any suggestions? :)

Comment: what are you trying to hook exactly? are you trying to insert some data to database or just verifying some data?

Comment: I am trying to verify that som extra data inserted is true or false. If false, user should not be able to submit the checkout and place an order. Basically it is just a question on how to hook something to checkout submit :)

Comment: haven't tried personally but if you are doing some data verification I believe you can run  a filter on ```woocommerce_add_``` like ```woocommerce_add_error``` and load your function on checkout page only https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_notice.html

Comment: Nice answer. But it is more a question on how to do custom checks to validate or not the place order function rather than how to do notifications:-) I would really like not to do core coding :/

Comment: did you try the filter? If you run a filter on error it won't obviously place the order and add error notice

Comment: @simond are you trying to do something after you select payment method and clicking "Place Order"?

Comment: @Reigel Yes correct! I would like to do the checks the right way=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something like this..

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'rei_after_checkout_validation');

function rei_after_checkout_validation( $posted ) {

    // do all your logics here...
    // adding wc_add_notice with a second parameter of "error" will stop the form...
    // wc_add_notice( __( "OMG! You're not human!", 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

    if (empty($_POST['captcha'])) {
         wc_add_notice( __( "Captcha is empty!", 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }

}
```

`$posted` is an array like this..

```
Array
(
    [terms] => 0
    [createaccount] => 0
    [payment_method] => cheque
    [shipping_method] => 
    [ship_to_different_address] => 
    [billing_first_name] => 
    [billing_last_name] => 
    [billing_company] => 
    [billing_email] => iamhuman@gmail.com
    [billing_phone] => 
    [billing_country] => PH
    [billing_address_1] => 
    [billing_address_2] => 
    [billing_city] => 
    [billing_state] => 
    [billing_postcode] => 
    [order_comments] => 
)
```

Comment: Too much awesomeness! Thanks a lot, U rock! :-)

Comment: This is not working for me ? Do i need to do extra things?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the dedicated action hook:

> woocommerce_checkout_process

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validate_course_enrolled');

function validate_course_enrolled(){
$cart_items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
$total_count = $cart_items_count + $quantity;

if( $cart_items_count >= 2 ){
    // Set to false
    $passed = false;
    // Display a message
     wc_add_notice( __( "You can’t buy more than one course", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
}
return $passed;
```

}